# Save different types of data in a List in C#

Tags: c#, printing

I have several data like name, ID, age, address, phone. Every time user input data, it will save to the `List<>`. I'm using `List<>` for each data. Is there any other option I could only use one `List<>`.  Which can save all the data?

This is my code.

```
List<String> list1 = new List<String>();
                list1.Add(name);
List<String> list2 = new List<String>();
                list2.Add(ID);
List<String> list3 = new List<String>();
                list3.Add(age);
List<String> list4 = new List<String>();
                list4.Add(address);
List<String> list5 = new List<String>();
                list5.Add(phone);

for (int a = 0; a < list.Count; a++) // Loop through List with for
{                        
    listBox1.Items.Add(list1[i]);
}
for (int a = 0; a < list.Count; a++) // Loop through List with for
{                        
    listBox2.Items.Add(list2[i]);
}
for (int a = 0; a < list.Count; a++) // Loop through List with for
{                        
    listBox3.Items.Add(list3[i]);
}
for (int a = 0; a < list.Count; a++) // Loop through List with for
{                        
    listBox4.Items.Add(list4[i]);
}
for (int a = 0; a < list.Count; a++) // Loop through List with for
{                        
    listBox5.Items.Add(list5[i]);
}
```

I also thought of using listbox to printout the data.  My other option is to print out every data in only one listbox.

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely, declare a class like this...

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid   ID      { get; set; }
    public string Name    { get; set; }
    public int    Age     { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone   { get; set; }
}
```

And use it like this..

```
List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();
personList.Add(new Person { Name    = "Max", 
                            ID      = Guid.NewGuid, 
                            Address = "Unicorn Lane, Unicorn World", 
                            Age     = 26, 
                            Phone   = "123456" });
```

Comment: +1 for using real terms (Person, personList) instead of meaningless terms like MyClass. +1 for using object initializer syntax.

Comment: then can i know how to retrieve the data from the list? im using listBox1.Items.Add(personList[0]); and it prints out "person"

Comment: Sure, although thats really a completely different question. To display the items correctly inside something like a listbox you need to set the DataValueField and DataTextField properties. Using the object above you would enter something along the lines of ListBox.DataValueField = "ID"; ListBox.DataTextField = "Name"; or declaratively something like this: <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="lstPerson" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID"></asp:ListBox>

Answer (score 1):

Why not create an object (class) with those fields.
Then you can just create an array of "user" objects.

Whenever the data is passed, you only have to create a new instance of the object and then add it to your array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a person object, set the properties for the person and add the person to the list

```
List<Person>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a **class** is the best solution for your question,the use `List<YourClass>`.

Answer (score 0):

There is one other option that you can use with the latest versions of C# if you hate to create a class for it. Use a Tuple.

```
var mylist = new List<Tuple<Guid,string,int,string, string>>();
myList.Add(new Tuple<Guid,string,int, string, string>(Guid.New(), "name", 18, "123    street", "1231231234"));
```

Later on, you can access it as

```
var firstId = myList[0].Item1;
var firstName = myList[0].Item2;
```